# Mono: IHttpAsyncHandler doesn't call EndProcessRequest

Tags: c#, asp.net, mono

I use ASP.NET IHttpAsyncHandler for async redirect Long Polling HTTP Requsets to other URL. It works perfectly with .NET 4.5 (Windows 7,8). But doesn't work with Mono (Mono JIT compiler version 3.2.8 (Debian 3.2.8+dfsg-4ubuntu1), Ubuntu 14.04). After completing request.BeginGetResponse AsyncCallback doesn't call EndProcessRequest.

```
    public bool IsReusable { get { return true; } }

    public IAsyncResult BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext context, AsyncCallback cb, object extraData)
    {
        var request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create("http://www.google.com/");
        request.Method = context.Request.HttpMethod;

         request.UserAgent = context.Request.UserAgent;
        request.Accept = string.Join(",", context.Request.AcceptTypes);

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(context.Request.Headers["Accept-Encoding"]))
        {
            request.Headers["Accept-Encoding"] = context.Request.Headers["Accept-Encoding"];
        }
        request.ContentType = context.Request.ContentType;
        request.ContentLength = context.Request.ContentLength;
        using (var stream = request.GetRequestStream())
        {
            CopyStream(context.Request.InputStream, stream);
        }
        return request.BeginGetResponse(cb, new object[] { context, request });
    }

    public void EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result)
    {

       // EndProcessRequest never called

        var context = (HttpContext)((object[])result.AsyncState)[0];
        var request = (HttpWebRequest)((object[])result.AsyncState)[1];
        using (var response = request.EndGetResponse(result))
        {
            context.Response.ContentType = response.ContentType;

            foreach (string h in response.Headers)
            {
                context.Response.AppendHeader(h, response.Headers[h]);
            }
            using (var stream = response.GetResponseStream())
            {
                CopyStream(stream, context.Response.OutputStream);
            }

            response.Close();
            context.Response.Flush();
        }
    }

    private void CopyStream(Stream from, Stream to)
    {
        var buffer = new byte[1024];
        while (true)
        {
            var read = from.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            if (read == 0) break;

            to.Write(buffer, 0, read);
        }
    }
```

I don't know reason of this strange beahaviour. I suppose this behavior is bug of HttpWebRequest class in Mono framework but I am not sure. May be are there any workarounds of this problem?

Comment: I don't know the answer but you are using terribly outdated technology. Replace all this APM stuff with async/await.

Comment: please file a bug in http://bugzilla.xamarin.com/ with a minimal testcase

Comment: @knocte, done. Bug 21467 - IHttpAsyncHandler doesn't call EndProcessRequest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We found some workaround of the problem by using ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem:

```
    public bool IsReusable { get { return true; }}

    public IAsyncResult BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext context, AsyncCallback cb, object extraData)
    {
        return new AsynchOperation(cb, context, extraData).Start();
    }

    public void EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) { }

    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) { }

    private class AsynchOperation : IAsyncResult
    {
        private AsyncCallback cb;
        private HttpContext context;
        public WaitHandle AsyncWaitHandle { get { return null; } }
        public object AsyncState { get; private set; }
        public bool IsCompleted { get; private set; }
        public bool CompletedSynchronously { get { return false; } }

        public AsynchOperation(AsyncCallback callback, HttpContext context, object state)
        {
            cb = callback;
            this.context = context;
            AsyncState = state;
            IsCompleted = false;
        }

        public IAsyncResult Start()
        {
            ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(AsyncWork, null);
            return this;
        }

        private void AsyncWork(object _)
        {
            var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(boshUri);
            request.Method = context.Request.HttpMethod;

            // copy headers & body
            request.UserAgent = context.Request.UserAgent;
            request.Accept = string.Join(",", context.Request.AcceptTypes);
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(context.Request.Headers["Accept-Encoding"]))
            {
                request.Headers["Accept-Encoding"] = context.Request.Headers["Accept-Encoding"];
            }
            request.ContentType = context.Request.ContentType;
            request.ContentLength = context.Request.ContentLength;

            using (var stream = request.GetRequestStream())
            {
                CopyStream(context.Request.InputStream, stream);
            }

            request.BeginGetResponse(EndGetResponse, Tuple.Create(context, request));
        }

        private void EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult ar)
        {
            var data = (Tuple<HttpContext, HttpWebRequest>)ar.AsyncState;
            var context = data.Item1;
            var request = data.Item2;

            try
            {
                using (var response = request.EndGetResponse(ar))
                {
                    context.Response.ContentType = response.ContentType;

                    // copy headers & body
                    foreach (string h in response.Headers)
                    {
                        context.Response.AppendHeader(h, response.Headers[h]);
                    }
                    using (var stream = response.GetResponseStream())
                    {
                        CopyStream(stream, context.Response.OutputStream);
                    }
                    context.Response.Flush();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception err)
            {
                if (err is IOException || err.InnerException is IOException)
                {
                    // ignore
                }
                else
                {
                    LogManager.GetLogger("ASC.Web.BOSH").Error(err);
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                IsCompleted = true;
                cb(this);
            }
        }
```